How to separate import and import type properly with eslint-plugin-import?
I'm using eslint-plugin-import in my React app.
There is a rule in that plugin which is named import/order. It allows you to make the order of imports inside your file.
I need all my import type to be the last in the list of imports. Like so:
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Page } from 'widgets/Page'
import type { FC } from 'react'
import type { ReducersList } from 'shared/lib'

Here's my config for that rule:
    "import/order": [
                "error",
                {
                    "groups": [
                        "builtin",
                        "external",
                        "internal",
                        "parent",
                        "sibling",
                        "index",
                        "object",
                        "type"
                    ],
                    "pathGroups": [
                        {
                            "pattern": "react",
                            "group": "external",
                            "position": "before"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": [
                        "react"
                    ]
                }
            ]

The problem is that "pattern": "react" in "pathGroups" leads to mistake in import type { FC } from 'react'. Mistake says that 'react' type import should occur before import of 'widgets/Page'
Is there a good option to make all import type from all groups to be the last one in the list of imports?
